# Relation of Chi-Square and Normal Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

$\chi^2$ distribution is defined to be
$$
X = \sum_i^n Z_i^2
$$
where each $Z_i$ is $~N(0,1)$

Supposing I have $(X_1,...,X_n)$, each $X_i$ follows normal distribution with unknown parameters. I can then standardize the model, so that I have $\hat{X_i} = \frac{X_i - \bar{X}}{S^*}$ follows standard normal. Now, I have $(\hat{x_1},...,\hat{x_n})$. Then, would

$$
\sum_i^n \hat{x_1}^2 
$$
follow $\chi^2$ distribution?

If not, how should I model it to follow $\chi^2$ distribution?

Comment: The $\dfrac{X_i-\bar X}{S^*}$ do not follow a normal distribution !

Comment: Are $\bar{X},\,S^\ast$ distributional parameters or sample parameters? For the latter, consider the [$F$-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Properties_and_related_distributions).

Comment: @J.G. Interestingly I know that I am supposed to use the fisher distribution but you mentioning it cleared my head and now I feel silly that I tried to do something with $\chi^2$ distribution

Comment: Notice $\bar X$ as well as $S^*$ are random variables while $\mu_X$ and $\sigma_X^2$ are just plain numbers!

Comment: Assuming from notation that $\bar X$ and $S^*$ are sample mean and sample sd, [exact distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/182087/119261) of $\hat X_i=\frac{X_i-\bar X}{S^*}$ is of course not normal. There's no apparent reason for $\sum_i \hat X_i^2$ to have a $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom The OP assumed $X_i$ follows normal distribution, and if $\bar{X}$ is the mean of $X_i$, $S^*$ is its standard deviation then $\hat{X}_i$ follows exactly the standard normal distribution as the OP said, right?
And if $X_i$ are independant, the sum must have the $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: @NN2 You make no distinction between sample moments and population moments. $\bar X\ne E(X_i)$

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information about the quantities involved that may help you get oriented.

It is $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i = \bar X)^2$ that has a distribution related to chi-squared.  Specifically, for normal data, $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$ However, $V = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2$ has $\frac{nV}{\sigma^2} \sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=n).$

Both relationships can be pivoted to find confidence intervals for $\sigma^2.$
Use the first when $\mu$ is unknown and estimated by $\bar X;$ the second when $\mu$ is known.

The second relationship follows directly form the definition of a chi-squared
random variable with $n$ degrees of freedom as the sum of squares of $n$ independent
standard normal random variables. The first is a little more difficult to prove.

Then $T^2 = \frac{(\mu - \bar X)^2}{S^2/n} \sim \mathsf{F}(\nu_1=1,\nu_2=n-1)$
and $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}} \sim \mathsf{T}(n-1),$ where $0\le T^2 <\infty$ and $\infty < T< \infty.$

Simulations of 100,000 samples of size five give a reasonably good idea
of the shapes of the distributions involved,

```
set.seed(2021)
n=5;  m=10^5; mu=50; sg=7
x = rnorm(m*n, mu, sg)
MAT = matrix(x, nrow=m)
a = rowMeans(MAT)
summary(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  36.05   47.91   50.01   50.01   52.13   62.99 

s = apply(MAT, 1, sd)
summary(s)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.3706  4.8542  6.4193  6.5896  8.1448 22.1255 

v = rowMeans((MAT - mu)^2)
summary(v)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
  0.3821  26.1829  42.6799  49.0846  65.0845 404.9011 

t = (a - mu)/(s/sqrt(n))
summary(t)
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-18.732518  -0.729211   0.003526   0.004822   0.745464  31.257069 

f = t^2
summary(f)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
  0.0000   0.1149   0.5438   1.9899   1.8092 977.0044
```

Below are plots of some of the quantities above; for clarity t and F
histograms are for truncated data.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
hdr1 = "CHISQ(4)"
hist(4*s^2/49, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main=hdr1)
 curve(dchisq(x,4), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
hdr2 = "CHISQ(5)"
hist(5*v/49, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main=hdr2)
 curve(dchisq(x,5), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
hdr3 = "T(4)";  xlb4 = "t in (-4,4)"
tt = t[t> -4 & t<4]
hist(tt, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", xlab=xlb4, main=hdr3)
 curve(dt(x,4), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
hdr4 = "F(1,4)"
ft = f[f < 5];  xlb5="f below 5"
hist(ft, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", xlab=xlb5, main=hdr4)
 curve(df(x,1,4), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]